# react-native 0.49 brackets after base class

Tags: reactjs, react-native, es6-class

`react-native init` (Version 0.49) generates an App-Class:

```
export default class App extends Component <{}> { .... }
```

now there are brackets after the base class (Component). can anybody tell me, what this notation stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is `flow` and it defines type of the component properties - in this case no properties are expected for `App`.

See more https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/

Comment: thx sodix! this may be flow syntax, but flow is not part of react-native

Comment: sorry sodix, you are right! it is flow: react-native@0.49 uses flow-bin@0.53